# What is difference between soft core on NIOS and hard core?

Tags: verilog, fpga, nios

I am learning FPGA recently. I have tried to use sdram, somebody recommends me use it through nios ii. But I see some articles using ip core on nios ii(c/c++) it may slow than you write through verilog? Why? Because Hardware(fast, parallel) and Software?

Comment: Soft core means the CPU is not part of the FPGA, it is actually synthesized and mapped into the FPGA at compile time. Hard cores, are items (IPs etc) that are physically located inside the FPGA.

Comment: This questions would be better suited for the [EE StackExchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

What is a soft-CPU? FPGAs are composed of, among other things, reconfigurable logic blocks (LUTs), Memory, and multipliers/DSPs. A soft CPU is a CPU made up of the FPGAs configurable logic. Nios II is Altera/Intel's flavour of a soft CPU. This differs from a hardened CPU like the ARM cores included in many [Altera/Intel](https://www.altera.com/products/soc/overview.html) and [Xilinx](https://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/soc/zynq-7000.html) SoC FPGAs. In these cases, the ARM cores in made of fixed transistors instead of FPGA fabric, and cannot be reconfigured for other purposes.

Why have hardened CPUs? They're typically faster than soft CPUs, take up less space, and don't consume any of the valuable FPGA routing. Since many designs use some sort of CPU, hardening one (like is done with many popular I/O interfaces) it produces an overall net gain. (If you don't need a CPU, you can simple buy a non-SoC FPGA.

As for using a CPU vs pure logic/hardware, there are also tradeoffs. Writing software is typically easier than Verilog, and your CPU will be set up to manage things like response times and other memory quirks. However, you'll be restricted by the CPU speed (Nios is typically 100-200MHz, depending on your FPGA), and the extra latency of needing to interface with a CPU, and the CPU instruction execution speed.

In a similar vein to why FPGAs are gaining popularity, pure-hardware circuit have specialization that can allow them to operate faster than a more multipurposed CPU (either soft or hardened). The tradeoff you get for that speed boost is the extra work involved in writing timing-accurate Verilog.